# How to implement an API which will run a python script with the data from the POST request

Tags: python, background-process, api-design, fastapi

I want to run a python script which basically monitors any changes happening to a particular directory (the directory to monitor is passed as part of the POST request). Every time the API is called (I'm using FastAPI), a new instance of the script has to be started to monitor that particular directory and send back a "success" message as response if the script was started successfully. Further I am planning to add another API endpoint that will stop the script that is running to watch a directory.

Can message queues like [RQ](https://python-rq.org/) or Celery be used to achieve this? Please note that I want new scripts to be started every time the API is called so multiple instances of the script should run at the same time. I am using watchdog module to monitor the file system.

I don't know how to do this in the correct way but this is what I have come up with so far where a new thread is created for each API call:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from schemas import Data # pydantic schema model for API
from threading import Thread

import filewatcher # the script that has to be run

@app.post('/register/event')
def register_watchdog(data: Data):
    th = Thread(target=filewacther.create_watchdog, args=(data))
    th.start()
    return {"status": "success"}
```

What is the best way to achieve this? One further question is, can I implement my script as a Linux service that can run in the background?

Comment: Is there actually a need to start multiple instances? Couldn't you instead add these directories to watch to the inotify watchlist when you need?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, it is rather trivial to call this function in the code if you need to return the result of directory browsing function.

```py
...
def register_watchdog(data: Data):
    return {"result": filewacther.create_watchdog(data)}
```

But if you want to run some time-consuming process in the background, you really should use AMQP with the workers. [RabbitMQ](https://www.rabbitmq.com/) with Celery is really the right choice for this, it will make it easy to scale your system.

> What is the best way to achieve this? One further question is, can I implement my script as a Linux service that can run in the background?

Yes, you can indeed run RabbitMQ together with Celery as a linux service in the background e.g. using [supervisor](http://supervisord.org/) ([example](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/hello-linux-celery-supervisor)), but this is not the best practice. Look in the direction of [containerizing elements](https://www.docker.com/resources/what-container) of your system. You can [wrap Celery in a Docker](https://hub.docker.com/_/celery) and make it easy enough to run that along with the AMQP service and your web application ([example](https://arocketman.medium.com/distributed-task-queue-with-python-using-celery-and-fastapi-4cd1ad112c0f)).

Comment: As per my requirement, each time a new event is registered with the API, one more task would have to be added and run. Is it possible to run these celery tasks in parallel? And is it possible to manage the task (pause it or stop it)?